# Using count down timer with tinter

Tags: tkinter

Having trouble implementing a count down timer. The code below works but creates and extra, unwanted window. Without TK as a class parameter and the Tk.__init line, I get an error about the "after" function. The error is:

> AttributeError: 'MakeGUI' object has no attribute 'after'

Thoughts?

```
    class MakeGUI(Tk):
        def __init__(self,master,width,height,color):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Falling Squares Game")
        # window not resizable either x or y
        self.master.resizable(0, 0)
        # make sure window on top
        self.master.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
        #self.master.after(1, lambda: self.master.focus_force())
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.canvas0 = Canvas(self.master,width=750,height=30,bg="light green")
        self.canvas0.pack()
        self.canvas1 = Canvas(self.master, width = self.width, height = self.height, bg = self.color)
        self.canvas1.pack()
        self.remaining = 0
        # set length of game to n seconds
        self.countdown(100)

    # count down timer
    def countdown(self, remaining = None):
        if remaining is not None:
            self.remaining = remaining
        if self.remaining <= 0:
            pass
        else:
            self.remaining = self.remaining - 1
            self.after(1000, self.countdown)

    def main():
    # create a Tk window
        win1 = Tk()
        win1x = 750
        win1y = 750
        # create the GUI
        c1 = MakeGUI(win1,win1x,win1y,"light blue")
```

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't generate the error you say it does.

As for the two windows, it creates two because you tell it to create two. The first one is this line of code:

```
win1 = Tk()
```

The second one is this line of code, because `MakeGUI` inherits from `Tk`:

```
c1 = MakeGUI(win1,win1x,win1y,"light blue")
```